# Gulp freeze on Waching code and realoding on changes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gulp

Sorry to ask this.. but I'm new at using GULP...

I'm using a template built with AngularJS and when I run the command gulp, the console show me the message "**Done Waching code and reloading on changes" but anything happen after several minutes...

It doesn't show any error, it just clean and then compile a lot of things and after that show me that message and nothing else happens.

I was googling this message but it doesnt say anything... Is there a reason for this or a log where I can look for the specific error?
Actually, I'm not sure what I'm expecting to happend.. the browser should be open whit the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're running `gulp.watch()`, it starts up a process that is watching your files. It has to keep the process running otherwise it wouldn't be able to recompile your code. This is fine though, this is the intended behavior of watch.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry to be so newbly with this... So, how can I see my webpage?    I saw that in the gulp.config file the server is localhost and the port is 3000. But when I enter to that address, nothing happens. I missing something? I need to have a webserver like Apache or something? Should the files be in an specific folder? If I just open the Index.html, nothing happen

Comment: I have this:
webserver: {
      webroot:          '.',
      host:             'localhost',
      port:             '3000',
      livereload:       true,
      directoryListing: false
    },

Comment: No worries! Everyone has to start somewhere. Yes, you will most likely also have to start your server after you run gulp with some sort of command like `node server.js` or something of the sort

Comment: Also, if this is the correct answer please mark as accepted with the check mark to the left of the solution :)

Comment: Thanks for all your help! It's difficult to move from jquery to angular+node+gulp :)
So I've already have a server.js working and I can see the page!!

If I'm right, I have to have two console open, one with node server.js and the other one with gulp running, right? or the server.js make gulp to run and to keep refreshing the sources?

Comment: Yeah exactly. No worries, it's pretty difficult to get up and running but once you do node is a great server side environment. super flexible too